# Extract all pixels values from GeoTIFF with Python

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, rasterio, pixel

I would like to recover the values of the pixels of a GeoTIFF of a single band. First I get the x and y coordinates and I would like to use them to access the pixel value. Here is my code:

```
   raster = rasterio.open('.../g.tif')
   br_pixel = (raster.width * raster.height) 

   liste3 = []
   i = 0   
   while i <= nbr_pixel:
      (x,y) = raster.xy(i,i)
      listX.append(int(x))
      listY.append(int(y))
   i = i + 1 
   l = list(zip(listX,listY))
   liste3 = raster.sample(l)
   print(liste3)

   <generator object sample_gen at 0x7f7ef5821c50>
```

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Please use the [edit] link to add more information to your question, we need to know what happens when you run this, compared to what you expected to happen.

Comment: Your `for` loop looks exceeding strange. Pixel count is a product of rows and columns, so you're trying to tear along the diagonal far past the actual size of the image. Recovering the X and Y coordinates along with pixel value could make an extraordinarily large list; raster format is used to avoid this cost, so you're running against paradigm, which usually causes spectacular failures. You may be trapped in an XY Problem; what is your actual goal?

Comment: my goal is to extract the x and y coordinates and the pixel values (ndvi)

Comment: Your code does nothing like your stated goal. You *try* to walk the diagonal, but the `while` is incorrectly structured, so you infinitely sample the zero-zero pixel. You need to spend some more time on the Python code structure before this is a GIS question. Start with a pair of nested `for` loops using `range` iterators over width and height.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that you want to read in all of the pixel values of a single band so that you access them with x and y values. I would do this by getting the entire band as a numpy array, then use the x and y indices of the array:

```
import rasterio
band_id = 1  # this assumes you want the first band, change to match the band number you want

raster = rasterio.open('.../g.tif')
band_arr = raster.read(band_id)  # band_arr is a numpy array of shape (raster.width, raster.height)
```

If you then want to get the pixel value at specific `x` and `y` indices:

```
pixel_value = band_arr[x, y]
```

---

**OP's comment:** I want to have a array of all pixels coordinates and pixels value. because i want to insert in a database.

OK. Beginning with `band_arr` from above:

```py
px_vals = []

for x in range(band_arr.shape[0]):
    for y in range(band_arr.shape[1]):
        px_vals.append({'x': x, 
                        'y': y,
                        'value': band_arr[x, y]})
```

The above will give you a `list` of `dict`s with keys `'x'`, `'y'`, and `'value'` which you could then insert into the database.