# Extract selected pixel values with their coordinates

Tags: python, rasterio, pixel

My goal is to get the coordinates of all pixels with a specified value (ex: maximum and minimum pixel values).

```
# imports
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import rasterio

# load tif
src = rasterio.open('./data/thhz.tif')

# read band
band = src.read(1)

# get maximum and minimal values
max = np.max(band)
min = np.min(band)

# convert raster into shapefile
# got this from https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/346288/extract-all-pixels-values-from-geotiff-with-python
### this process is too slow from here need to use other methods
px_vals = []

for x in range(band.shape[0]):
    for y in range(band.shape[1]):
        px_vals.append({'x': x, 
                        'y': y,
                        'value': band[x, y]})

# convert list to dataframe
vals = pd.DataFrame(data=px_vals, columns=['x', 'y', 'value'])

# convert dataframe to geopandas 
vals['geometry'] = gpd.points_from_xy(vals['x'], vals['y'])
vals = gpd.GeoDataFrame(vals, geometry='geometry', crs='EPSG:4326')

# transform coordinates with affine of raster
# get affine matrix with src.profile
vals['geometry'] = vals.affine_transform([0.001, 0.0, 2.616837667, 0.0, -0.001, 11.815923996])
# this also was not well converted

# slice values with coordinates
min_pixels = vals[vals['value'] == max]
max_pixels = vals[vals['value'] == min]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just worked out a solution

```
def coordinates_and_values(raster, pixel_values):
    """
    this function extracts longitude and latitudes of list of raster pixel values
    raster: load raster with rasterio
    pixel_values: list of pixel values 
    exception: pixel value must be found more than one time in raster else len of float error
    """
    df = pd.DataFrame()                         # create dataframe
    raster_band = raster.read(1)                # read raster band
    for i in pixel_values:                      # iterate between list of pixel values
        rows, cols = np.where(raster_band == i) # extract row and column numbers for each pixel
        rows, cols = transform.xy(raster.transform, rows, cols) # transform row and column numbers to coordinates
        values = np.array([i] * len(rows))      # create array containing n pixel value of n coordinates
        df_i = pd.DataFrame(zip(rows, cols, values), columns=['lon','lat', 'pixel']) # create dataframe for one pixel value
        df = df.append(df_i)                    # append to get dataframe of lon and lat of list of pixel values
    return df
```

Example:

```
coordinates_and_values(src, [-7, -6, -5, 6])
```

Answer (score 1):

Looping over a numpy array will always be slower than using vectorized numpy operations only. Try:

```
min_rows, min_cols = np.where(band == np.min(band))
max_rows, max_cols = np.where(band == np.max(band))
```

`band == np.min(band)` gives back a boolean array, [broadcasted](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to be in the same shape as `band`, and containing `True` where the element is equal to the min value.

[`np.where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) gives back indices where the condition is true, if you only specify the first argument.

Comment: Is it possible to get the coordinates instead of #row & #cols?

Comment: min_lons, min_lats = transform.xy(thhz.transform, min_rows, min_cols)

Comment: max_lons, max_lats = transform.xy(thhz.transform, max_rows, max_cols)

Comment: from rasterio import transform

Comment: Please add these to your solution. Thanks